# UICollectionView issue with Select/Deselect cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

Hello everyone I have a problem with the selection of cells in my collection.
To manage the selection and deselection, of course, I have provided the delegated methods `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`

Everything works correctly but I have a problem that I can not solve. In short, when I selected a cell I would like to have the possibility to deselect the last cell selected by reselecting the cell itself ... for example

I will use a name for the cell to make you understand my problem better

The user selects the cell **"22"** to deselect it. I would like the user to reselect cell **22** again and deselect it.

I tried to use `allowMultipleSelection = YES` and this seems to be in the system that I prefer but the problem is that the cell is not reselected, all the other entries selected and so it is wrong ... How can I solve this problem ... ??

This is the code I utilize for select and deselect the cell

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SmartCalendarDayCell *calendarDayCell = (SmartCalendarDayCell *)[self.dayCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    calendarDayCell.day.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#D97E66" setAlpha:1];
}
```

---

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SmartCalendarDayCell *calendarDayCell = (SmartCalendarDayCell *)[self.dayCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    calendarDayCell.day.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want your `collectionView` can only select 1 cell at a time and if selected cell is clicked again, it will be deselected. If I'm misunderstanding anything, please tell me.

**First**

- You shouldn't change `textColor` of `day` in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` methods. Because when you scroll `collectionView`, cells will be reused and color of `day` will be wrong for some cells.
- To resolve it, using [property selected of `UICollectionViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620130-selected?language=objc).

  SmartCalendarDayCell.m

  ```
  - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];

    if (selected) {
      self.day.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#D97E66" setAlpha:1];
    } else {
      self.day.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
  }
  ```

**Second**

- To deselect selected cell, you should check and do it on [collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618095-collectionview?language=objc) method.

  ```
  - (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
      [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
      return NO;
    }

    return YES;
  }
  ```

For more detail, you can check my demo repo [here](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/table-view-seleted-cell).